# Getting error while installing realm through cocoapods

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, xcode8

I am getting this strange error while installing realm on **xcode 8**, cocoa pods version **cocoapods-1.2.0**

The error is -

> Installing Realm (2.4.3)
>
> [!] /bin/bash -c
> set -e
> sh build.sh cocoapods-setup
>
> ./scripts/swift-version.sh: line 59: [: =: unary operator expected
> No version of Xcode found that supports Swift 3.0.2

All other pods work great.

Thanks for the help in advance.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Which exact Xcode version are you running? xcodebuild -version

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hey for anyone looking for an answer -

I did find out that I had the second xcode installed (xcode 7), due to which the command line tools which were chosen were of xcode 7.3 which was causing the error.

So what I did was, I went to - 
xcode >> preferences >> locations >> CommandLineTools

and selected the commandLineTools for the latest Version(xcode 8).

Thanks...

Comment: Beautiful. This is a general answer not limited to the realm.

Comment: Yes indeed, but it was realm error prompt that pulled me to this.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue

```
xcode version - 8.1

error - No version of Xcode found that supports Swift 2.2
```

so I did the following

> pod 'RealmSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa',
>   :commit => '2faba712db752fba8e85639e7023ce35ada0fb15', :submodules =>
>   'true'

For reference you may have a look to this link https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4534